# What to return for invalid user auth for OWIN method AuthenticateCoreAsync

Tags: owin

When implementing the AuthenticationHandler<...> class, what should you return when a user authentication fails for the method AuthenticateCoreAsync?

Answer (score 0):

You should return `return new AuthenticationTicket(null, (AuthenticationProperties)null);`

See https://github.com/IdentityModel/Thinktecture.IdentityModel/blob/master/source/Hawk/Owin/HawkAuthenticationHandler.cs#L69

Comment: That's not necessarily a good source for proof. We are doing the same thing, and it seems to cause a login redirect loop. I've also seen people return just null too. So where is the docs that tell us what is supposed to be returned.